# How to understand the first selicho for Asoro B'Teves

Tags: number, fast-days, selichot

I do not understand the first selicho (in the [Rosenfeld edition, p 343](http://www.amazon.co.uk/THE-AUTHORISED-SELICHOT-WHOLE-YEAR/dp/B000JLK49W)) for Asoro B'Teves.

The first line reads, “I remember the distress that befell me; **three** blows he inflicted on me this month.”

Later on, it reads, “For these I strew ashes on my face, for these **four** calamities I exclaimed etc.”

The footnote explains the four as being: translation of the Torah into Greek, the death of Ezra, the approach of the Babylonians to Jerusalem, Ezekiel receiving the news of Jerusalem's fall.

The numbers in these two lines do not agree. 
Could it be that the "three" refers to the 8th, 9th and 10th of Teves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the Art Scroll siddur with translation of this selicha (page 848/849)

The next few verses give the list of three

1. Translation of the Torah into Greek on the ninth of Teves
2. Ezra the Sofer died on "this day"
3. On the tenth the prophecy of Yechezkel ben Buzi was commanded.

Since this is when he was informed of both the siege and the fall, the two are combined into one item in the list.

Farther down Art Scroll puts the list of four in brackets

1. the translation of the Torah
2. the death of Ezra
3. the siege of Yerushalayim
4. the fall of Yerushalayim

Apparently the last two mean that the prophecy (the third tragedy in the first list) was considered two actual events (the siege and the fall).